# tomcat7 and EL in a jsp page; pageContext.request.contextPath empty?

Tags: jsp, el, tomcat7

My JSP page contains:

```
<script>
    var bt_wd40_appurl = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
</script>
```

view/source shows "" for the value. No errors I've found so far.

my web.xml specifies version 2.5.

Comment: It will be empty if you deployed the webapp on ROOT. Sure that you did deploy it on a context path? Note that the context path doesn't contain the scheme/domain part of the URL, it's a domain-relative URL.

Comment: Oh, duh! IDEA did exactly that. Make an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will be empty if you deployed the webapp on ROOT. See also its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> ### getContextPath
>
> `java.lang.String getContextPath()`
>
> Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request. The context path always comes first in a request URI. The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/" character. **For servlets in the default (root) context, this method returns "".** The container does not decode this string.

Are you sure that you *did* deploy it on a context path? Note that the context path doesn't contain the scheme/domain part of the URL, it's a domain-relative URL.