# Unable to locate js file in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I went through all the SO question posted for this problem. But I didn't find solution.

I created project Spring MVC project using IntelliJ Idea and I am using Tomcat 7.42
My project structure is as shown in picture.

**My JSP code**

```
<html>
<head>

<script src='/js/index.js' type="text/javascript"/>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>${message}
          ${pageContext.request.contextPath}
          ${pageContext.request.contextPath}
     </h1>

     <form:form action="/personDetails"  commandName="command">
     <p><form:errors path="*" cssClass="error"/></p>
         Age :<form:input path="age" cssErrorClass="myErrorClass"></form:input><br>
         Name:<form:input path="name"></form:input><br>
         City:<form:input path="city"></form:input><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Save">
      </form:form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now my problem is I am unable to get js file located and also  `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is coming as blank.

What would be reason for the same?

[image]

Comment: Are you running your app in the tomcat root? What is the URL you are using to view that page? Also, try adding `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` to the top of your JSP.

Comment: I am running application using IDE and my jsp is absolutely fine just to shorten the code I have not added <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> in above code. I removed and updated code to avoid confusion

Comment: Are you viewing the page with a context path? What is the page URL!!!!

Comment: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} is giving me blank and my url is http://localhost:9999/pageDetails

Comment: So you are running your app as a ROOT tomcat app - therefore `contextPath` should be blank. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11581460/249327

Comment: So how can I solve problem of locating js from IDE.

Comment: Most likely reason is related to the answer below. Do you have a `<mvc:resources>` entry, if so show it to us.

Comment: I don't have.If suppose to add then what I should add because below answer is giving me 404

Comment: have you tried `<%= application.getContextPath() %>/js/index.js` in src?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have resource mappings in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml in for serving up static resources, maybe like following?

```
<resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/**" />
```

Comment: Not working fine. Issue may with the application running from IDE

Comment: @ShoaibChikate You need to then change your `<script>`'s `src` attribute to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/index.js`.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Open your browser's network terminal and check the request that your browser is making to get the javascript resource. What response code is it getting back? Make sure that the path it's sending the request is appropriate. Then change it accordingly if it isn't.