# spring security mvc application noHandler found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring MVC with security and I am getting following error whenever I access a page. Also, images, js, and CSS files do not load.

```
Mar 25, 2014 11:34:14 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sam/img/hagal_logo.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' Mar 25, 2014 11:34
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sam/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' Mar 25, 2014 11:34:14 AM                                                                
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sam/js/jquery.actual.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' Mar 25, 2014 11:34:14 AM 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sam/js/jquery.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' Mar 25, 2014 11:34:14 AM
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sam/js/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'



<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5">    

<display-name>Some</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
     classpath:spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

and here is my dispatcher-servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.entity" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.service" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />  
      <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />  
      <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />  
      <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />  
 </bean>  

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
      <property name="hibernateProperties">  
       <props>  
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>      
       </props>  
      </property>  
</bean>
```

and this is my spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <form-login login-page="/login.html" 
        default-target-url="/login-success.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/login-error.html" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.html" />

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: As this are static resources we should mention then into spring-servlet as they are static

Comment: thanks @ShoaibChikate for reply. As i am new to spring ,will you please show me how to do that ,or just give me a reference link

Comment: Follow possible solutions in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699240/unable-to-locate-js-file-in-jsp

Comment: not solved by your link, in fact there is no tag like <resources> in dispatcher-servlet.xml schema

Comment: Post your web.xml and configuration.

Comment: @FaizAli, you have to include mvc xsd in that so you can get mvc:resources.  Please post more code so we can debug your problem.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate added code please have a look

Comment: And no need of specify mvc-dispatcher-servlet in contextConfigLocations as I will be found automatically by servlet container based on name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add mvc namespace.

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/**" /> //whatever ur path of js and images is.
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Thanks. Solves the problem. For JavaConfig version please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Shoaib Chikate's answer, JavaConfig version :

In your app config java file please add :

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }
```