# spring mvc, css is not working

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

The css and javascript is not work on my page.

My home.jsp

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
</body></html>
```

The headTag.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <s:url value="/resources/css/test.css" var="testCss"/>
    <link href="${testCss}" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
```

The web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->

   <!--   <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc</param-value>
    </context-param> -->

   <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>hibernate</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my app servlet-comntext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <!-- <Enable @Controller> -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.a72.coursapp.controller" />

        <!-- resources mapping -->
        <mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources/"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

The test.css

```
h2 {
    color:red;
}
```

css location: src/main/webapp/resources/css/test.css

folder structure

```
-src
--main
---webapp
----resources
-----css
------test.css
-----js
-----fonts
----WEB-INF
-----views
------fragments
-------headTag.jsp
------home.jsp
```

What's wrong? Thanks in advance!

If look to source code page in firefox, page has test.ccs style, but it has this log:

```
    Pivotal tc Runtime 3.0.0.RELEASE/8.0.9.B.RELEASE - Error report
    HTTP Status 400 - description
 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Pivotal tc Runtime 3.0.0.RELEASE/8.0.9.B.RELEASE
```

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699240/unable-to-locate-js-file-in-jsp

Comment: post hierarchy structure of project, if you can..

Comment: @ShoaibChikate thanks, but it's not help for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that your problem is the line:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
```

Don't think you can include anything behind WEB-INF with jsp:include.
It would anyway be rather unorthodox to call a view directly, they should be called by controllers.
Presumably if you are using spring you have a controller which calls that view? If so, then call the uri provided by the controller.

Otherwise I guess you need to move the jsp to a position that is not hiding behind WEB-INF.

Comment: I change it to 'fragments/headTag.jsp', it work, headTag.jsp include to home page, but css not work.

Comment: Go back to doing things the simple way. Move your /css folder into the webapp folder and then call it direct with <link href="/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this move your CSS and JS folder under WEB-INF 
eg. if you are keeping your files like..

> WEB-INF/resources/css/test.css

then change path in servlet-comntext.xml

```
  <!-- resources mapping -->
        <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/"/>
```

change in headTag.jsp page

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/test.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not help :( Nothing has changed.

Comment: can you give current folder structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you problem is base path. Try out:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/test.css" />" />
```

Comment: I tried it before, also tried just link on css and spring:url. Not work.

Comment: If your page is using https and you include your CSS file via http, browser is blocking mixed content.